# laravel-snappy pdf not showing in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-snappy

I am using laravel-snappy to generate pdfs and show them in the browser. I am getting a blank page in return.The code I am using is this.

```
return PDF::loadView('emails.flightInvoice', $data)->inline();
```

I used the below code to save the PDF and it is working.

```
PDF::loadView('emails.flightInvoice', $data')->save('invoice.pdf');
```

can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The `inline()` method requires a filename

Try

`return PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data)->inline('filename.pdf');`

Comment: I'm having the same issue as Kashif and even with the filename, I still get a blank response. The inline method works on my local dev machine, but not on Ubuntu Linux production server. Any other ideas?